# Using API Gateway to download already gzipped files from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an API frontend to a few things, one of those is an S3 bucket containing lots of files.

When I setup a resource that integrates with my S3 bucket, this works perfectly fine for standard text data, but fails for files that are already gzipped.

How do I tell API Gateway to just pass through the gzipped file as a binary stream?

I need to use API Gateway for authentication, so I can't just get around it by using the s3 bucket to serve my files.

I also need gzip encoding turned on for nearly every other endpoint, so turning that off will cause other problems to already working endpoints.

Comment: Existing questions on StackOverflow seem to focus on "how do I get API gateway to gzip my data", not my problem. A few other questions exist, but their answers are from 2017 or earlier any options they refer to have been renamed (for instance, binary handling in the settings menu).

Comment: `fails for files that are already gzipped` — could you be more specific what fails? (if other resources work fine, maybe check the content type returned).

Comment: Thanks. If the file is not a gzip file, then it is returned correctly and downloads successfully. If it is a gzip file, the resulting file is not a valid gzip file. It does seem to be close, having the filename in the contents and being about the right length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "other" working content - are there only text files or as well  binary content files?

You have to set some parameter when handling binary content with the default (not http-only) API Gaeway. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html  (this is only my assumption about the problem as you still failed to provide any repeatable and validable example, how the API Gateways is providing the content? As Lambda? Code? )

As well there's 10MB limit for API Gateway payload. If you want to return longer content (actually - I'd use it for all content), the API Gateway can return a pre-signed URL for S3 (or web distribution) so the client could download the content of any length from the S3 bucket (directly or through the CloudFront).

Comment: Marking as correct as this led me to the answer. All binary files were failing, and the main problem was that the Content-Type of the response was being set to "application/json". When "Integration Response" says "passthrough", they only mean the body, not the headers as I was thinking. You need to go to "Method Response", add "Content-Type" as a header, then go to Integration response and map it through using a Mapping Value of `integration.response.header.Content-Type`